# Positioning hint within multiline EditText - TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` that has 4 lines (min=4; >4 scrolls). The `EditText` is embedded in a `TextInputLayout`. The hint displayed for this seems to be centered vertically. I'd like it at the start of the 1st line, naturally.

**Important Edit**: Testing without `TextInputLayout` allows for the hint to be positioned effectively. The problem lies with this. Any insight into how to resolve it is appreciated.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:hint="What's going on?"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="4"
        android:minLines="4"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
        android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/custom_scrollbar_style"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black_semi_transparent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="140"
        android:textColor="@color/black_semi_transparent" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

[image: Comparison of EditText]

Comment: have you tried `gravity="left"`

Comment: Yes. I've tried `left`, `top`, `top|left`, `start`.

Comment: Well, one solution is to use paddingTop=20dp

Comment: look into this https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText. Helped me a lot and is easy to use

Comment: @Vishal Rathod, that did not work. That only places padding between the hint and the input area.

Comment: @Smashing, I previously used that third party EditText, however I would like to use Android's newly updated EditText, thanks.

Comment: @McGuile but hint already displaying top left in my code

Comment: Edited post with important info.

Comment: This is extremely annoying, did you find a workaround? My first attempt to use TextInputLayout and of course it is too buggy. *#&%(@#*$ android

Comment: Filed bug report https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=179720

Comment: @GregEnnis Unfortunately I couldn't. TextInputLayout is relatively new and I couldn't find anything helpful on it. I replaced it entirely for a RelativeLayout in the end so I've lost some functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug has been fixed in the v23 support libraries:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=179720

Comment: Still it does not positioned well - with ``android:gravity="bottom"`` - it's closer to bottom then in the singleLine TextInputLayout.